# open dialog not open correctly material angular 11

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog, modal-dialog

I have a problem opening my dialog material. My dialog does not open correctly

1. First I import `MatDialogModule` in `AppModule`
2. Second I declare in the constructor `MatDialog`
3. Third I declare in the constructor `MatDialogRef`

Html File (`booklist.component.html`)

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="onCreate()"><mat-icon>add</mat-icon>Create</button>
```

Ts File (booklist.component.ts)

```
constructor(private bookService: BookService, public dialog: MatDialog) { }
onCreate() {
    this.bookService.initializeFormGroup();
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.width = "350px";
    this.dialog.open(BookComponent,dialogConfig);
  }
```

Ts File (`book.component.ts`)

```
constructor(public service: BookService,public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<BookComponent>,@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }
```

In my application when I click on the book page after I click on the create button, my dialog doesn't open correctly, Any idea  please?

this is the link of my project in stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/github/lnquaidorsay/bibliofront or
exactly link: https://parigwxyr.github.stackblitz.io/books

Answer (score 0):

Add to your AppModule
`entryComponents: [BookComponent],`

in example:

```
  entryComponents: [BookComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

If you use Ivy in your angular project, you don't need to add entryComponents but you project seems like not support Ivy idk why...

Go to settings -> enable Ivy. It should fix this problem

[image]